# Why do I get error when I try to return a string from a function in loadChildren in Angular?

Tags: angular

For some reason I have to add the string `'../home/home.module#HomeModule'` to loadChildren, but how come a function that returns the same string does not work? I want to be able to concat the string based on some variables such as if it is going to be ahead of time compilation because then I can't do `../`, I have to do `./` as the root path.

Any workaround for this?

```
function loadHome() {
    return '../home/home.module#HomeModule';
}

const mainRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: MainComponent,
        children: [
            { path: '', loadChildren: loadHome()}
        ]
    },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: '/' }
];
```

I am getting the error: `EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find module '../home/home.module'`